# Excel Advanced Filtering Issues - Advice Needed

Tags: excel, vba

So basically I have a main table, and I want to filter that data to another table (normally easy) but I want this based upon 2 criteria. e.g. I want to filter the data of a specific department but only for the current month. The way I display the current month in the main table is by inserting the date from a userform and then by formatting that cell to just display the month. However, when using advanced filter I use the column headings that I want to filter e.g. department: mens, month: november (worked out using =now() then formatting to just display the month) but when I'm running the filter it's not picking out the information at all.

I think this lies with the way the month is worked out and displayed but I can't figure out another way to do this. Any help is greatly appreciated.

I'm also open to trying a new method of just selecting data for the current month if anyone has a cleaner way, as I'm sure there is one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to use a formula in your criteria to specify what month you want to extract. But it's not terribly intuitive. Take a look at this sample. My starting list is the range A1:B7. My criteria is in range D1:E2. The Department is straightforward; I just entered "3". (Obviously, without the quotes.) But instead of a Month criteria, I added "GetMonth" and entered the formula shown in the formula bar. You can name this whatever you want, but it can't be the same as one of the headers in your source list. (Yeah, I checked.) The formula checks to see if the current month of the date in cell B2 is 12, which is December, and returns TRUE or FALSE. You could use 11 for November. The advanced filter will apply the reference to cell B2 that's in the formula in a relative fashion to all cells in the Month column. And Viola! my output in range A10:B11 is what you'd expect it to be.

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the great answer, this looks like it will sort of do what I need but my problem is I'd really need a dynamic way to of the month changing automatically instead of typing "11" or "12" for example - any ideas? Thanks so much for the help!